# jQuery: Find first two children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using jQuery, what would be the most efficient way to find the first two children of a parent element, if one is an `h1` and the other is a `p`. My code isn't working right now, and I would like to accomplish this using best practices.

**CSS**

```
div > *{
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('div h1').show();    
$('div p:first-child').show();
```

**Edit** I'm actually working with multiple DIVs. I didn't think it would make a difference, but it looks like I was wrong.

Comment: If you don't actually need to use jQuery, you could use this CSS rule: `div > h1:first-child, div > h1:first-child + p { display: block; }`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try,

```
$('div').children().slice(0,2).show();
```

Incase if you have more that 1 div, then try like below,

```
$('div').each (function () {
    $(this).children().slice(0,2).show();
});
```

Comment: Aha, yes, right. Well, you learn something new every day, and sometimes more than one thing a day. :)

Comment: @colindunnn Got to use `.each` if there are more that one div. See my edits.

Comment: This selector would work without using each `$('div').find('h1:first, p:first').show()`

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder Smart. God, I love StackOverflow.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I am not sure, but I prefer to keep my jQuery function call minimal.. may be it is just me.

Comment: Vega, `$('div').find('h1:first, p:first').show()` vs `$('div').each (function () {
    $(this).children().slice(0,2).show();
});` You tell me which is minimal :-P

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I would love to test it, but unfortunately.. jsperf is down. Anyways, `:selectors` are usually slower.. but not sure if `children()` is even slower or not... then again I may be wrong. Also for small pages, it doesn't even matter.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about performance. I am talking about readability and maintainability. Now that you mention that i am interested in seeing the performance of the selectors as well.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I agree. In readability point of view your version is clear.. mm but not maintainability.. It is different if I decide to show 2 `p` tags.. in that case `:lt` is better. Oh  btw, You should post that as an answer.. I think OP is interested in your suggestion.

Comment: Vega, i agree with your assessment. I had already posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

an alternative way to `slice()` method:

```
$('div').children(':lt(2)').show()
```

(but I recommend the slice too, especially for large collections)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/94EU7/

```
$('div :lt(2)').show();
```

Comment: Also, I agree with Interstellar_Coder. If you *really* want the first h1, and the first p, and not just the first two children, then you should use his approach as it's clearer what're your're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').children().slice(0, 2).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user the [less than](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector like following

```
$('div > *:lt(2)').show();
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/sWkTg/)

Answer (score 1):

A descriptive selector would be

```
$('div').find('h1:first, p:first').show();
```

This makes it clear what your intent is and what elements you're selecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div p:first-child,div p:nth-child(2)').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want the `eq()` function, like this:

```
$("div").children().eq(0); // first child
$("div").children().eq(1); // second child
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to use jQuery for this.

```
var firstChild = div.firstChild;
firstChild.style.display = 'initial';
firstChild.nextSibling.style.display = 'initial';
```

Comment: Do you mean `.style.display = 'none'`?