# Removing last div inside a div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have the following structure

```
<div id="BigBox">
    <div class="SmallBox">
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="SmallBox">
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="SmallBox">
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment I fetch new `ele` divs with this:

```
setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.html",
                    cache: false
                }).done(function( html ) {
                            $("#BigBox").html(html);
                            })
                        });
            }, 60000);
```

This updates replace all the content of BigBox and `update.html` returns

```
 <div class="SmallBox">
             <div class="ele highlight"></div>//new ele
             <div class="ele"></div>
             <div class="ele"></div>
    </div>
```

---

What I want to do now is have a way of telling of how many new `ele` are coming in, and then remove that number from the bottom up and push the new `ele` from top to bottom,
so when new `ele` are pushed into the top `SmallBox` which can only hold 3, the last div in that small box get pushed down to the next `SmallBox` and so on until the last `SmallBox` where the extra old `ele` there disappears from the page. Is that possible or is replacing the whole `html` is a better approach?

I hope this make sense

Comment: Count and slice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659283/jquery-find-first-two-children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to keep only 3 `SmallBox`es, each which has capacity 3. The following adds new elements at the top, and gets rid of extras at the bottom.

```
.done(function( html ) {
    var numBoxes = 3;
    var capacity = 3;

    $eles = $(html);
    $('#BigBox').find('.SmallBox').unwrap();
    $('#BigBox').prepend($eles);
    for (var i = 0; i < numBoxes; i++ ) {
        var s = i * capacity;
        $("#BigBox").find("div.ele")
                    .slice( s, s + capacity )
                    .wrapAll("<div class='SmallBox' />");
    }
    $('div.ele').not('div.SmallBox > div').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the number of rows in your response.

```
setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "update.html",
                    cache: false
                }).done(function( html ) {

                            //number of ele rows added
                            var eleCount = $('.ele', $(html)).length;

                            $("#BigBox").html(html);
                            })
                        });
            }, 60000);
```

In terms of removing and adding things you can use jquery to remove and add the elements if you know the index of what you wanted to remove. For example you could do :

```
$('.ele:nth-child(4)', $(html)).remove();
```

This would remove the fourth element from the list.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wT4E9/9/)?

```
// save fixed elements/data
var $bigBox = $('#BigBox'),
    $smallBox = $bigBox.children().first().clone().empty(),
    capacity = 3;

done = function(html) {
    var $newElems = $(html),
        $currentElems = $bigBox.find('.ele');

    $currentElems.unwrap().slice(-$newElems.length).remove();
    $bigBox.prepend($newElems);
    $currentElems = $bigBox.children();

    var numBoxes = Math.ceil($currentElems.length / capacity);

    for(var i = 0; i < numBoxes; i++) {
        $smallBox.clone()
          .appendTo($bigBox)
          .append($currentElems.splice(0, capacity));
    }
};

done('<div class="ele highlight">10</div>');
done('<div class="ele highlight">11</div><div class="ele highlight">12</div>');
```

Note that with this code you can choose how many elements one smallBox should contain and are completely free in how many elements get added, it constructs as many containers as it needs to wrap all `.ele`ments.