# Show certain count fo line in <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

How can I show for example only 2 lines (not the 1st and the 2nd lines) of the text in such div using jQuery or JavaScript. Also I need to control text length and cut it if its too long

```
<div class="introtext">
    first first first firstfirstfirst<br>
    second second second second second second second<br>
    third third third third third<br>
    <br>
    fifth fifth fifth fifth fifth fifth fifth
</div>
```

This markup was generated and it should show only `n` lines of text in this div

I want to see something like this:

```
first first first 
firstfirstfirst second seco...
```

And markup like this:

```
 <div class="introtext">first first first firstfirstfirst second seco...</div>
```

Comment: Do you only want to hide the last 3 lines, or do you want to get rid of them completely?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659283/jquery-find-first-two-children

Answer (score 1):

you could use css :

```
.introtext{
line-height:15px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3QGB/1/)

Comment: He can mix this with jquery using: `var e = $('.introtext'); var lines = 2; e.height((e.css("line-height").replace("px", "") * lines) + "px");`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the line after n you can try this:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.introtext')
var content = element.innerHTML;
var lines = content.split('<br>');
lines.length = 2;
content = lines.join('<br>');
element.innerHTML = content;
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFHG8/)

Comment: for SEO this solution is better than hidding

Answer (score 0):

Add a css `class` with jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/K3aJ3/

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the lines that you don't need from DOM, using jquery:

```
var $secondBr = $(".introtext > br:nth-of-type(2)");
var $children = $(".introtext").contents();
var index = $children.index($secondBr);
$children.slice(index).remove();
```

This finds the second <br> element in the text, determines its index among all of container's children, and then removes all children starting from this element.